# Python Qt5, dialog window, Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, исключения, pyqt5

У меня прога делится на несколько блоков: ГУИ - шка, основной код программы и самописный класс с exception - ами.

Пишу бота на selenium и счас начал делать гуишку. Создал первое окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия на войти должна отработать часть кода связанный с авторизацией. 
 и дальше бот начинает работать.

Дело в том, что основной код я писал со следующей конструкцией

```
response = ex.BadResponse()

try:
    do smth
except:
    response.error('error message')
```

Класс с Exception:

```
class BadResponse(Exception):

    def error(self, message):
        self.__printf(message)
        self.type_ = 'error'
        self.body = message
```

Т.е. без гуи у меня все ошибки писались просто в консоль. С появлением гуи хочу, чтобы все ошибки выводились как модальное окно, но никак не пойму как это реализовать.

На том же qt5 создал `UI_Dialog()`. Как внутри `response.error(message)` вызывать модальное окно и чтобы весь код переставал работать , пока пользователь не нажмет `Ok`?

main.py:

```
class Win(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    version = 1

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        #QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('ScartProject Bot - v.' + str(self.version))
        self.ui.login_input.setText('dtumakov')
        self.ui.password_input.setText('111')
        self.ui.signIn_btn.clicked.connect(self.sign_in_btn_clicked) 

    def sign_in_btn_clicked(self):
        login_val = str(self.ui.login_input.text())
        pass_val = str(self.ui.password_input.text())
        remember = self.ui.remember_checkBox.checkState()

        if not login_val or not pass_val:
            pass
            #call modal window 

        payload = {
            'login': login_val,
            'password': pass_val,
            'remember': 'on' if remember else 'off'
        }

        browser, url, settingsPath = bot_init()

        if not authorization.Auth(browser=browser, url=url, payload=payload, settingsPath=settingsPath).browserLogIn():
            pass
            #call modal window
        else:
            bot_working(browser)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Win()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Пример места вызова модального окна:

```
def __browserGetPage(self):
    try:
        get_request(self.__url)
        self.__browser.get(self.__url)
        self.response.success('Page successfully received')
    except:
        #Here should be raise modal window
        self.response.error('Site is not available')
```

Answer (score 1):

Помогли call_back функции.

В блоке main.py создал метод вызова модального окна:

```
def open_modal(self, type_, title, message):
    if type_ == 'error':            
        QMessageBox.critical(
            self,
            title,
            message
        )
    elif type_ == 'warning':
        QMessageBox.warning(
            self,
            title,
            message
        )
```

Дальше при вызове любого метода из другого класса в конструктор кидаю свой метод `self.open_modal` как колбэк ф-ю:

`Bot(_dialog_ = self.open_modal).get_params()`

Оттуда уже вызываю свой класс с эксепшенами:

```
class Bot():
    # Изначальные настройки бота хранятся в данном файле
    settingsPath = './Bot/settings.ini'
    baseLink = cg.get_config(settingsPath)['Settings'].get('url') + cg.get_config(settingsPath)['Settings'].get('authPrefix')
    response = ex.BadResponse()

    def __init__(self, _dialog_, url = None):
        try:
            self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        except:
            self.response.warning(self._dialog_, 'Невозможно запустить экземпляр браузера. Возможно браузер уже запущен. Попробуйте еще раз')
```

И собственно так выглядит мой класс с эксепшекнами:

```
class BadResponse(Exception):

    def error(self, _dialog_, message):
        self.__printf(message)
        _dialog_('error', 'Ошибка', message)

    def message(self, message):
        self.__printf(message)

    def __printf(self, message):
        print(message)

    def success(self, _dialog_, message):
        self.__printf(message)
        _dialog_('success', 'Ошибка', message)

    def warning(self, _dialog_, message):
        self.__printf(message)
        _dialog_('warning', 'Ошибка', message)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Win(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    version = 1

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('ScartProject Bot - v.' + str(self.version))
        """
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.login_input.setText('dtumakov')
        self.ui.password_input.setText('111')
        self.ui.signIn_btn.clicked.connect(self.sign_in_btn_clicked) 
        """

        self.login_input    = QLineEdit('dtumakov')
        self.password_input = QLineEdit('111')
        self.signIn_btn     = QPushButton("Зарегистрироваться")
        self.signIn_btn.clicked.connect(self.sign_in_btn_clicked)
        self.remember_checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Запомнить")

        centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)

        layout = QGridLayout(centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.login_input,       0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.password_input,    1, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.remember_checkBox, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.signIn_btn,        2, 1)


    def sign_in_btn_clicked(self):
        login_val = str(self.login_input.text())
        pass_val  = str(self.password_input.text())
        remember  = self.remember_checkBox.checkState()
        print(f"login_val-{login_val}, pass_val-{pass_val}, remember-{remember}")

        if not login_val or not pass_val:

# call modal window vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            QMessageBox.information(
                self,  
                "Информация", 
                "Что-то пошло не так! \n вставьте сюда что хотите->`{}` ".format(login_val))

            print(" # call modal window ")
            return False
            print(" Это не напечатается никогда !!!")
# call modal window ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        payload = {
            'login':    login_val,
            'password': pass_val,
            'remember': 'on' if remember else 'off'
        }

        """
        browser, url, settingsPath = bot_init()
        if not authorization.Auth(browser=browser, url=url, payload=payload, settingsPath=settingsPath).browserLogIn():
            pass
            #call modal window
        else:
            bot_working(browser)
        """

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Win()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, но основная проблема в том, что нужно вызывать модальное окно вне основного класса (с ГУИ) приложения, а как только отрабатывает какой-нбдь эксепшен внутри кода выполнения основной программы. Т.е. в меине вызвать модальку не проблема, а когда вызывается внутри кода, то модалька появляется и зависает, после чего крашится приложение, пытался основной код засунуть в отдельный поток, но не помогло